# Invoke lambda instances from lambda and wait for the longest to comple

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I have a lambda and I want to invoke multiple lambdas instance and wait for the longest to complete.

I already checked online and found very interesting threads but none of them helped me achieve what I want.

Here's the code:

Lambda as promise

```
invokeVideoRenderer = (params) => {
    const param = {
      FunctionName: 'myFunction',
      InvocationType: 'Event',
      Payload: JSON.stringify({ body: params })
    };

    return new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => {
      this.lambda.invoke(param, (error, data) => {
        if (error) {
          reject(error);
        }
        resolve(data); <--- it always returns { StatusCode: 202, Payload: '' }
      });
    });
  };
```

the loop where I invoke the different lambdas

```
const promises = [...Array(totalNumberOfLambdaToInvoke).keys()].map(
    async (part: number) => {

      
      const body = {
        // body
      };

      const request = await invokeVideoRenderer(body);
      return request;
    }
  );

  const results = await Promise.all(promises); <--- here I want to wait for the longest to complete
```

The lambda I am invoking:

```
const myFunction = async (event, context, callback) => {
  try {
    //...code
    callback(null, {
      status: 200,
      body: JSON.stringify({
        status: "SUCCESS",
      }),
    });
    return;
  } catch (error) {
    callback(null, {
      status: 500,
      body: JSON.stringify({
        status: "FAILED",
        errorMessage: error,
      }),
    });
    return;
  }
};
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: An InvocationType of Event tells Lambda to invoke the child Lambda asynchronously. Hence the Lambda service responds with 202 (Accepted) response immediately. Meanwhile the child Lambda function executes.

Comment: how should I change the code so it waits for the lambda to complete?

Comment: Also, note that you don't have to manually create/resolve promises with AWS SDK. Just use `return this.lambda.invoke(params).promise()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An InvocationType of Event tells Lambda to invoke the child Lambda asynchronously. Hence the Lambda service responds with 202 (Accepted) response immediately. Meanwhile the child Lambda function executes.

If you want it to execute synchronously, then don't provide an InvocationType of Event. Either remove it entirely to get the default, or explicitly set it to RequestResponse (which is the default).

Note: it's typically not ideal to invoke Lambda functions synchronously if you can avoid it, because you are paying for both Lambdas concurrently.

Comment: I changed the InvocationType to RequestResponse but still, my main lambda is not waiting for the child lambdas to complete.

Comment: Your map should simply `return invokeVideoRenderer(body);`. No need for the async declaration or awaiting anything.